# Post ID on Keyup AJAX/PHP/MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have the below code. Currently it submits only the first_name which is exactly what I want and it does that on the fly without the page refreshing.

However I need to parse an ID number along the same ajax request through the hidden id field.

Can anybody suggest any ideas to help me?

Thanks in advance

CODE:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function ajax_post(){
    // Create our XMLHttpRequest object
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // Create some variables we need to send to our PHP file
    var url = "my_parse_file.php";
        var fn = document.getElementById("first_name").value;
    var vars = "firstname="+fn+;
    hr.open("POST", url, true);
    // Set content type header information for sending url encoded variables     in the request
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    // Access the onreadystatechange event for the XMLHttpRequest object
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
            var return_data = hr.responseText;
            document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = return_data;
        }
    }
    // Send the data to PHP now... and wait for response to update the status div
    hr.send(vars); // Actually execute the request
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "processing...";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Ajax Post to PHP and Get Return Data</h2>
<input type="hidden" name="my_id" value="1234">
First Name: <input id="first_name" name="first_name" type="text" onkeyup="ajax_post();">  <br><br>
<div id="status"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: var vars = "firstname="+fn+'&my_id='+document.getElementById("my_id").value;

<input type="hidden" name="my_id" value="1234" id='my_id'>

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>TITLE</title>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
function ajax_post(){
 var $elementStatus = $('#status');
 $elementStatus.html('processing...');
 var url = 'my_parse_file.php';
 var data = { firstname : $('#first_name').val() };
 var success = function(responseText, textStatus, jqXHR) {
  if(jqXHR.status != 200)
   return;

  $elementStatus.html(responseText);
 };
 $.post(url, data, success);
};
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <h2>Ajax Post to PHP and Get Return Data</h2>
 <input type="hidden" name="my_id" value="1234">
 First Name: <input id="first_name" name="first_name" type="text" onkeyup="ajax_post();">  <br><br>
 <div id="status"></div>
</body>
</html>
```